# Diagnosing 302 Redirect in Rails login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to log in under one certain user account on my server I'm presented with a `302 Redirect`, which I can't really figure out how to debug.

Here is the log output:

```
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:44.863837 #29152]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:44.864715 #29152]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uWIySEF1QN/2wg+0YpOzGDOPBcFKYtdiJAvuvwrZ5uE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:45.349905 #29152]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.com/
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:45.350241 #29152]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 485ms (ActiveRecord: 247.6ms)
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:45.669553 #29152]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 12.228.244.22 at 2016-10-28 11:58:45 -0500
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:45.673424 #29152]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.044037 #29152]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.com/
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.044249 #29152]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 371ms (ActiveRecord: 70.1ms)
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.315053 #29152]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 12.228.244.22 at 2016-10-28 11:58:46 -0500
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.317108 #29152]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.516814 #29152]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.com/
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.517015 #29152]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 200ms (ActiveRecord: 48.6ms)
I, [2016-10-28T11:58:46.727266 #29152]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 12.228.244.22 at 2016-10-28 11:58:46 -0500
```

So, it appears the user is able to log in, and the fault lies with the `PagesController#home` method, which really doesn't have a ton:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if current_user && current_user.company
      get_company_and_locations
      get_network_hosts
      get_network_hosts_at_risk
      @network_hosts_snip = @network_hosts_at_risk.sort_by{ |h| -h.security_percentage }.first(5)
      get_company_issues
      @issues = @issues.sort_by{ |i| -i.cvss_score }.first(5)
      @deferred_issues = @company.deferred_issues.last(5)
      @deferred_hosts = @company.deferred_hosts.last(5)
    else
      redirect_to new_company_path
    end
  end

  def vm_download
    get_company_and_locations
  end
end
```

The methods are the top of `PagesController#home` are helpers which have been in place for some time and never caused issues before:

```
def get_company_and_locations
    @company = current_user.company
    @devices =  Device.where(company_id: @company.id).order(name: :asc)
    @locations = if @company
      current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
    else
      []
    end
 end

def get_network_hosts
    get_company_and_locations
    @network_hosts = []
    @company.locations.each do |l|
      l.network_hosts.each do |h|
        @network_hosts.push(h)
      end
    end
end

def get_network_hosts_at_risk
    get_company_and_locations
    @network_hosts_at_risk = []
    @company.locations.each do |l|
      l.network_hosts.each do |h|
        next if h.security_percentage == nil
        if h.security_percentage < 99
          @network_hosts_at_risk.push(h)
        end
      end
    end
end

def get_company_issues
    get_company_and_locations
    get_network_hosts_at_risk

    @issues = Set.new
    @network_hosts_at_risk.each do |h|
      if h.last_test
        results = h.last_test.results
        results.each do |r|
          if r.ignore_date == nil
            r.ignore_date = 30.days.from_now
            r.save
            @issues.add?(r.issue)
          else
            @issues.add?(r.issue)
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

The `views/pages/home.html.erb` is relatively long, so I'll hold back on posting it here unless someone thinks that could be the issue.

So, where does one go from here to fix the `302`?

Comment: What actually happens after the user logs in? Do they get stuck in an endless redirect loop or something else?

Comment: @Rocco Yes, it eventually times out and they're told in the browser window that they were `Redirected too many times`

Comment: I assume you have ruled out the obvious and checked that current_user has a company and it isn't doing the `redirect_to new_company_path` - does it enter the if block?

Comment: I'd guess it's one of the following things, 1) It's going to the `else` case in your `home` action, redirecting there, then there's something there causing it to redirect back (though that might show in the logs), 2) There's some redirect in the view causing it to go back to home. I'd use the pry gem with `binding.pry` breakpoints to track when the redirect happens

Comment: @Rocco What's odd is that this doesn't happen in development, only on the production server.

Comment: Could be some environmental variable. Also could be what @henners66 said, that specific user doesn't have an associated company

Comment: Are there any before_actions on your ApplicationController which may be causing the issue?

Comment: @rebagliatte there are, but none that I've added recently that would make this problem suddenly appear

Comment: @henners66 User does have a company

Comment: hmmm ok ... then worth checking your action is actually being entered. I suspect like the others its a before_action causing this issue. Does your home action get entered at all? Are you using CanCan by any chance?

Comment: @henners66 how can I go about testing that in production?

Comment: ah didn't catch that earlier - only happens in production. If this is happening for one user but consistently - maybe you could replicate the data associated with that user in your development environment, including roles and rights if they are defined.

Comment: Right, @godzilla74 are you using any authorization handler, like cancancan or pundit?

Comment: @rebagliatte I'm using `devise`

Comment: Well devise is technically your authentication gem, you may use authorization gems like cancancan or pundit in addition to it.

Comment: @rebagliatte I believe devise installs cancan as a dependency

Comment: It is not a dependency, however, if you do have cancancan installed please check your `ability.rb` file

Comment: Here's more info on how to debug abilities: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had a 302 redirect problem which threw me back to login after a successful login. Solution: User had no roles.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing everyone's collaborations in order to troubleshoot this you can:

- Make sure the user's credentials are correct.
- Make sure the user has access to the current resource if you are using an authorization handler. For example when using the 'cancancan' gem you should check your ability.rb file.
- Troubleshoot the issue with a debugging gem such as 'pry', 'byebug' or 'better_errors'
- Check ENV variables if the issue is only reproducible on a specific environment

Answer (score 0):

Devise gem will throw 302 redirection on multiple cases.

(for example, non confirmed user will get 302 redirection)